# Spring não consegue se comunicar com o RabbitMQ (Docker)

Tags: spring, docker, rabbitmq

Subi o RabbitMQ e a aplicação no docker através do docker-compose, o container do RabbitMQ roda ok, mas a aplicação em spring não consegue se comunicar, dando erro:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMQConnection': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused*

Alguém sabe o pode ser? Segue abaixo os códigos:

```
**DOCKER-COMPOSE**
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

```
**DOCKERFILE DA APLICAÇÃO SPRING**
FROM openjdk:17
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Quando testo subindo a aplicação local com o Rabbitmq no docker, funciona normal.

Answer (score -2):

1  - Acho legal vc utilizar uma imagem rabbit com shovel, para vc conseguir enviar e receber as mensagens manualmente, tenho uma imagem pronta aqui
https://github.com/GuilhermeCesar/rabbit-shovel-jms/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml

2 - Vc precisa gerar as exchanges e filas programaticamente, https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/